# Запарсить случайное значение из списка

Tags: python

Как можно запарсить случайное значение из списка? Список выглядит следующим образом:

```
['значение1', 'значение2', 'значение3']
```

Comment: Что такое "запарсить" в вашем понимании?

Comment: Если не секрет, что вы такое разрабатываете, что важна скорость в 12мс?

Answer (score 3):

Используйте функцию choice

```
import random

list = ['значение 1', 'значение 2', 'значение 3']
print(random.choice(list))
```